# SQL code in Rnw document with knitr

Tags: sql, r, knitr, r-markdown, rnw

I used the following `sql` code in `.Rmd` document. However, I want to use the same SQL code in `.Rnw` document.

````
```{r label = setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, max.print = NA)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "survey.db")
dbListTables(db)
```


```{sql, label = Q1, connection=db, tab.cap = "Table Caption"}
SELECT * 
  FROM Person;
```
````

Would prefer to get code formatting and output printing facility.

Comment: Not sure if you saw this already (nor if it helps): http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/

Comment: Thanks @Frank for the link. I have seen that already but it is not useful.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question - are you just looking for something like [this](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/b27b682db8ed2261dc5c2b04b326f78a)?

Comment: @CL for your comment. I tried your code and getting this error: `Writing to file SQL2.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (label = setup, SQL2.Rnw:6)
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of “verbatim”, “tex”, “hide”
Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions -> check -> match.arg
Execution halted`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: I think you're using Sweave instead of knitr. Please check your RStudio settings. Plus, it seems like there is no implicit `LIMIT` in RNW documents, so you'd better add something like `LIMIT 10` to your query. As soon as this works, we can turn to the question of how to format the output nicely ...

Comment: Thanks @CL for your help. It is working. Would highly appreciate if you change your comment to answer and also guide how to get good formating. Thanks

Comment: I'll do both as soon as I figured out *how* to do it. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porting the RMarkdown to RNW requires some tweaking:

- Of course, chunk delimiters need to be adjusted: The RNW equivalent of ```` ```{r, echo=FALSE} ```` is `<<echo=FALSE>>=` and RNW chunks end with `@`. (See the [minimal RNW example](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal.Rnw).)
- Importantly, while chunks in RMarkdown documents always specify an engine, the engine in RNW is implicitly R unless the option `engine` is set. So ```` ```{r} ```` becomes simply `<<>>=`, but the equivalent of ```` ```{sql} ```` is `<<engine="sql">>=`.
- RMarkdown includes some very useful magic when embedding SQL chunks, see [knitr Language Engines: SQL on rmarkdown.rstudio.com](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#sql). By default, results are rendered as a nice table and only the first 10 results are printed. In RNW, we need to take care of this on our own.

For embedding SQL in RMarkdown, note that the SQL connection must be passed to the SQL chunk via the `connection` option. The option `output.var` can be used to specify the name of the object to which the result of the query will be assigned.

A simple solution (see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39356883/1)) would just assign the SQL result to an object, say `res`, using `output.var` and add another R chunk that prints `res` nicely, e.g. using `xtable`. However, there is a more elegant approach using [hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/):

<sub>The example uses the [SQLite sample database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download/sqlite-sample-database/?wpdmdl=94) from [sqlitetutorial.net](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/). Unzip it to your working directory before running the code.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
<<include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(DBI)

knit_hooks$set(formatSQL = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (!before && opts_current$get("engine") == "sql") {
    sqlData <- get(x = opts_current$get("output.var"))
    max.print <- min(nrow(sqlData), opts_current$get("max.print"))
    myxtable <- do.call(xtable::xtable, c(list(x = sqlData[1:max.print, ]), opts_current$get("xtable.args")))
    capture.output(myoutput <-do.call(xtable::print.xtable, c(list(x = myxtable, file = "test.txt"), opts_current$get("print.xtable.args"))))
    return(asis_output(paste(
      "\\end{kframe}", 
      myoutput,
      "\\begin{kframe}")))
  }
})

opts_chunk$set(formatSQL = TRUE)
opts_chunk$set(output.var = "formatSQL_result")
opts_chunk$set(max.print = getOption("max.print"))

@

<<echo=FALSE, results="hide">>=
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "chinook.db")
@

<<engine = "sql", connection=db, max.print = 8, xtable.args=list(caption = "My favorite artists?", label="tab:artist"), print.xtable.args=list(comment=FALSE, caption.placement="top")>>=
SELECT *  FROM artists;
@

\end{document}
```

A new chunk hook `formatSQL` is added. (Chunk hooks run whenever the corresponding chunk option is not `NULL`.) After a chunk with `engine="sql"`, it reads the SQL results into `sqlData`. Then, it uses `xtable` to print the first `max.print` rows of the result.

By default, the chunk hook `formatSQL` is activated (i.e. it is globally set to `TRUE`) and SQL results are stored in `formatSQL_result`. The chunk option `max.print` controls the number of rows to be printed (set it to `Inf` to print *all* rows, *always*).

The table produced by `xtable` is highly customizable. The chunk option `xtable.args` is passed to `xtable` and `print.xtable.args` is passed to `print.xtable`. In the example these options are used to set a caption, a label and to suppress xtable's default comment.

Below the generated PDF. Note that syntax highlighting for non-R code in RNW [requires](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/f02600d24a9628c8a376df41078756dc9e63bfc2/NEWS.md#new-features-11) installing [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.php) and adding the directory to path (Windows).

[image: Output]

Comment: Great @CL. works like a charm. Would appreciate if you guide how to put the caption on the top of the table. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Just pass `caption.placement="top"` to `print.xtable`.

Comment: Thanks @CL. for your help. There are two more thing to modify, `knitr2pdf` command from `knitr` show the `xtable` output on console which is not required. Also would like to know how to use `caption.placement="top"` and `connection=db` globally rather than locally. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 1) `xtable` output in console: See edit. 2) see `?print.xtable`: global option `xtable.caption.placement` 3) global `connection=db`: Don't think that this is possible.